# deployed Nodejs REST API on AWS using elastic beanstalk - Error cannot find custom module

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wrote my first nodejs application.
It works fine on my macbook but when I try to deploy it on AWS elastic beanstalk,I get below error .

/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log

```
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
module.js:338
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '**./routes/userprofile**'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/main.js:7:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

It seems nodejs is not able to resolve the path for my custom module 
userprofile which resides under Routes directory.I have tried moving userprofile.js to the root, but it can still not resolve that.

This is the code in main.js which loads all the modules

/ Load Our Modules

```
var express = require('express');    

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    

var userprofile = require('./routes/userprofile');
```

Problem it looks like is at this line  require('./routes/userprofile')

Does anyone have an idea , what I could be doing wrong?
Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.